# Finding a vector in a subspace of a Hilbert

Tags: functional-analysis

I'm stuck in the following problem:

> Let $H$ be an infinite dimension separable Hilbert Space and $\{e_{n}\}$ a Hilbert basis for $H$. $\forall \epsilon >0$ Find explicitly a vector $x_{\epsilon} \in span\{e_{1}-e_{2},e_{2}-e_{3},...\}$ such that $\|x_{\epsilon}-e_{1}\|< \epsilon$

I've proved that we can find that vector since $\|x_{\epsilon}-e_{1}\|< \epsilon \iff e_{1}\in \overline{span\{e_{1}-e_{2},e_{2}-e_{3},...\}}$, and $\overline{span\{e_{1}-e_{2},e_{2}-e_{3},...\}}$ turns out to be $H$.

From there, I'm quite lost. I'd really appreciate any hint or approach.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$x_N:=\sum_{n=1}^N \frac{N-n+1}{N} (e_n - e_{n+1})$ converges to $e_1$ since

$$||e_1 - x_N||^2 = \sum_{n=2}^N\left|\frac{N-n-N+n-1}{N}\right|^2+\left|\frac{N-N+1}{N}\right|^2=\frac{N-1}{N^2}+\frac{1}{N^2}=\frac{1}{N}$$

converges to zero as $N \to \infty$.

To get the formula note:
$$\sum_{n=1}^N a_n (e_n-e_{n+1}) = a_1 e_1 + \sum_{n=2}^N (-a_{n-1}+a_n)e_n - a_N e_{N+1}$$

Comment: In the last formula, you mean $\sum_{n=2}^N (-a_{n-1}+a_n)e_n$, don't you?

Comment: @Whoknows yes, you are right.